# Getting a 400 Bad Request error when uploading file to OneDrive through REST

Tags: c#, rest, post, onedrive

I am trying to upload a file to OneDrive using REST but am seeing a 400 bad request error when I try to do so. This is my code:

```
//Where I call it
//fileLoc being C:\\path\\test.doc
HttpUploadFile("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.xxxxxxxx/files/" + "?" + access_token, @fileLoc, "file", "application/octet-stream");

public static void HttpUploadFile(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType)
        {
            log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
            log.Debug(string.Format("Uploading {0} to {1}", file, url));
            string boundary = "A300x";// "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.KeepAlive = true;
        wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();

        rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

        string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName, "TEMPTEST.docx", contentType);
        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
        rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileStream.Close();

        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
        rs.Close();

        WebResponse wresp = null;
        try
        {
            wresp = wr.GetResponse();
            Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
            log.Debug(string.Format("File uploaded, server response is: {0}", reader2.ReadToEnd()));
            MessageBox.Show("Success!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error uploading file", ex);
            if (wresp != null)
            {
                wresp.Close();
                wresp = null;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error!" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            wr = null;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone see what my problem would be? I initially had my scope not set to be able to write but have corrected that so it is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that content-disposition header is wrong.  The [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#page-4) says the header should look like

```
Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=example.html
```

Comment: From this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx#uploading_files The documentation says it should be multipart/form-data, I believe all the examples I've seen use this as well

Comment: I see what you mean now, I posted this in the MSDN forums originally and it was their html editor that changed Content-Disposition: form-data into Content-Dis-data.

Comment: @Bryan Have you tried using HttpClient to do this.  I have been successful uploading files to skydrive using it.  Not saying that what you are doing won't work, it's just HttpClient has some much nicer classes to do this stuff.

Comment: I was mostly going off of example code I found which had worked for another user, I'll try out HttpClient this weekend but it seems like getting a Bad Request error wouldn't be related to that, here's hoping!

Comment: @Bryan I have an example that has worked for me https://github.com/tavis-software/Link/blob/master/Samples/SkyDriveApiTests.cs  It uses my own link class as a request factory, so you'll have to work around that a bit, but it will give you an idea of how to use HttpClient.

Comment: @Bryan Awesome, glad to hear it.